# Exiting a for loop from an if in the for loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm getting "A flight is available matching this information"
            "Passenger's details recorded and booking completed"

but then I'm also getting "There are no flights flying to this destination"

```
for (int k = 0;k <=4; k++)
{
    if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase(flights[k].getDestination()))
    {
        k = 5;

        System.out.print("\nEnter desired day of departure: ");
        day = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\f");

        if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(flights[k].getDay()))
        {

            if (flights[k].getBookedSeats() < 100)
            {

                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setName(name);
                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setAddress(address);
                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setEmail(email);
                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setOnFlight(k);
                flights[k].increaseBookedSeats();

                System.out.println("\nA flight is available matching this information");
                System.out.println("Passenger's details recorded and booking completed");

            }else{
                System.out.println("\nThere are no seats available on this flight");
            }
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("\nThere are no flights flying to this destination on this day");
        }
    }else if(!destination.equalsIgnoreCase(flights[k].getDestination()) && k==4)
    {
        System.out.println("\nThere are no flights flying to this destination");
    }

}
```

Comment: you should show us what `flights[k].getBookedSeats()` does ?

Comment: god forgive me, but you can use break with label too ;-) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/BreakWithLabelDemo.java (ok, not really)

Comment: @user636363 if u run the code then u provide departure date once in the code ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `break` statement inside your `if` condition to ensure that the loop breaks.

Comment: Thanks a million. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here occurs when you find a valid flight for your passenger before the loop has finished running through each iteration. setting `k` to 5 in your if statement is a step in the right direction, but does not work because you then use `flights[5]` throughout the rest of the block.

You *can* use a `break` statement instead of `k = 5`, but if you want to ensure your code will be easily maintainable in the future, you can make your intentions clear by using a while loop with a boolean specifying when you are done.

```
int k = 0;
bool done = false;

while (!done && k <= 4)
{
    if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase(flights[k].getDestination()))
    {
        k = 5;

        System.out.print("\nEnter desired day of departure: ");
        day = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\f");

        if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(flights[k].getDay()))
        {

            if (flights[k].getBookedSeats() < 100)
            {

                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setName(name);
                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setAddress(address);
                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setEmail(email);
                passengers[0 + bookedSeats].setOnFlight(k);
                flights[k].increaseBookedSeats();

                System.out.println("\nA flight is available matching this information");
                System.out.println("Passenger's details recorded and booking completed");

                // added this line:
                done = true;        
            }else{
                System.out.println("\nThere are no seats available on this flight");
            }
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("\nThere are no flights flying to this destination on this day");
        }
    }else if(!destination.equalsIgnoreCase(flights[k].getDestination()) && k==4)
    {
        System.out.println("\nThere are no flights flying to this destination");
    }

    k++;
}
```

Some people think that using `break` is fine, and in many cases I agree with them; however, when you come back to look at your code (or someone else does), it's nice to know that a `for` loop will absolutely execute the number of times that it specifies, but a `while` loop could exit early. It just makes things easier in the future.

Comment: In this case, why not just add the extra condition to the `for` loop? I.e., `bool done = false; for (int k = 0;!done && k <=4; k++) { … }`.  That seems cleaner than a while loop with the increment hidden inside.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That works just fine, but it's not really in the *spirit* of for-loops. The important thing is that you pick a convention (breaks, compound condition for, while, etc.) and stick to it consistently.

Comment: you have proposed one solution,can u provide the pblm in the OP code ??

Comment: I agree about convention, but I think in this case, having the loop termination conditions, and the loop update updates in one place probably makes it easier to see what's going on.  "OK, we've got a normal for loop except for an extra `done` condition…"

Comment: @NiksTyagi I'm not proposing a different solution than what LukeWillis provided;  on the contrary, I agree with Luke's solution.  I'd phrase it a little bit differently in code, but it would be a different expression of the same idea.

Comment: Ok u make some change in the code,which are efficient but my qustion is what is the issue in current code ? Why the if and else if condn got printed ??

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You make a good point. I think it mostly comes down to preference, but I agree that it's helpful to see everything on the same line.

Comment: Perhaps, but that often just means that the loop is doing too much and you need to apply a few `extract method` refactorings to simplify the code. For example, in this case if the code for booking flights was extracted out of the for loop, it might become so simple that the `break` would be obvious, and thus not an issue.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help. Appreciate it.